# Good class to identify browser and OS

Tags: php, user-agent

Is there any descent class that are capable to identify browser, its version and operating system?

I have tried default php function get_browser but results returned was wrong, it could not recognise non of my browsers (IE,Opera,Chrome,FF) except firefox but with wrong version.

Comment: Why get_browser result's wrong ? Can you give an example ?

Comment: Just to clarify, on PHP User's Manual there are some examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

Comment: Do you have an up-to-date browsecap.ini file?

Comment: I know that is not what you're asking, but browser detection simply doesn't work 100% of the time. It has a long history of deceit and disappointment ;) .

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to server, so I guess it's what my hosting provides.

Comment: @Eray all I get is "Default Browser" for most of the browsers IE, Opera, Chrome, Safari

Comment: @Nazariy, can you check 2nd example (http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) ? What returned for $array["parent"];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at phpbrowscap: https://github.com/garetjax/phpbrowscap

Use it like this:

```
$bc = new Browscap('/path/to/temp/dir');
$current_browser = $bc->getBrowser();

echo "<pre>";
print_r($current_browser);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Browscap consumes excessive ammounts of memory on the webserver.... not an option for me.